# Common Lisp - CCL, why a warning when passing a global to a local function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ccl

I’m learning Common Lisp, using CCL.
I get a warning when I use a global variable locally.  Why does CCL provide this functionality?  What is the purpose of this?

```
(setf n 75)

;;;This function works, but gets a warning about
;;;n being an undeclared free variable.
(defun use-global ()

(write n)
)

;;;This function works without warnings.
(defun global-to-local (x)

(write x)
)

(use-global)
(global-to-local n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Setf` and `setq` do not introduce new variables, they modify existing ones.

In order to define something like global variables, use `defvar` or `defparameter`.  These are conventionally written with a leading and ending `*`, and they are automatically declared *globally special*.  This means that whenever you re-bind them, this binding is in effect for the entire call stack above it, whatever functions you call from there etc..

In your example, the toplevel `setf` did not do that, so when compiling the function `use-global`, the compiler does not see that `n` is meant as such and issues the warning.  In correct and idiomatic Common Lisp code, this warning should generally be treated as an error, since it then indicates a misspelling or typo.

Comment: Thanks, it's all better now.  I'm using the older pdf version of "Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation."  Perhaps the newer version instructs on code as you have it.

Answer (score 2):

The warning provides little value.  The variable is bound by a prior top-level assignment, which creates a binding in the [global environment](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_g.htm#global_environment) making that variable a global variable. It simply being accessed, which is likely what is intended by the programmer.

An unbound variable warning is very valuable when no definition of a variable is seen because it catches misspellings of variable references. But a top-level `setf` or `setq` should be noticed by the implementation and treated as a definition.

It is useful to have a warning for cases when a variable is defined by a top-level `setf` and then later subject to a `let`:

```
(setf n 42)

(let ((n 43)) (func))
```

Here, it looks like the programmer might be expecting `n` to be a special variable, but it wasn't defined that way. `func` will see the top level binding of `n` which holds 42, and not the lexical `n` which holds 43. So there is a good reason to have a diagnostic here. The intent of the code requires `n` to have been declared via `defvar` or `defparameter`, or proclaimed special.

(Of course, we cannot warn about `(let ((n 43)) ...)` when no top-level `n` has been seen, because this is the usual situation for the vast majority of lexical variables.)

There is a bit of a defect in ANSI Common Lisp in that the section *[3.1.2.1.1 Symbols as Forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_abaa.htm)* says that there are only three kinds of variables: dynamic, lexical and constant. A dynamic variable is one that is declared special, and so according to this reasoning, `setf` is not enough to create a dynamic variable. However, section [3.1.1.1](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_aaa.htm) clearly spells out that there exists a global environment. Confusingly, it says that it contains bindings that have indefinite extent and scope, and that it contains dynamic variables. But then "dynamic variable" is defined in the glossary as being a variable with a binding in the dynamic environment, and a dynamic environment is defined as containing bindings with "dynamic extent". So that can't be the global environment. You know, that one which 3.1.1.1 says contains dynamic variables!

Anyway, all this ANSI confusion has created the misconception that `setf` or `setq` cannot create a variable, which lends support to bogus compiler diagnostics.

Comment: "But a top-level setf or setq should be noticed by the implementation and treated as a definition." -> AFAIK the standard does not say anything about that and what kind of definition it would be.

Comment: `func will see the top level binding of n which holds 42` - not necessarily. We hope that this is usually the case, but it is undefined in CL. For example CMUCL by default uses (d?) a dynamic binding, since it declares N to be special, globally.

Comment: This is not the forum to discuss this I think (perhaps #lisp might be: I have no idea where people talk about this any more), but the point is that, for a top level binding, dynamic extent and indefinite extent are identical, since, well, it's the top level: there is nothing above it, and the distinction depends on there being some level above the level where the binding is established.

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling suggests in Common Lisp is it done as something like:

```
(defvar *n* 75)

(defun use-global () (write *n*))

(use-global)
```

Note the asterisk that decorate global names by convention.